# How can I order 2 tables differently before joining them with a UNION clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, sql-order-by, union

In the query below, both of the tables run individually and give the right output separately. But when I try to combine them using the union, the order in which the second table is arranged is disrupted. How can I fix it to give me to proper combined output of both tables?

```
(SELECT CONCAT(name,'(',LEFT(occupation,1),')')
FROM occupations
ORDER BY name)

UNION 

(SELECT CONCAT('There are a total of ', COUNT(*),' ',occupation,'s.')
FROM occupations
GROUP BY occupation
ORDER BY COUNT(*),CASE WHEN occupation = 'Doctor' THEN 1
                    WHEN occupation = 'Singer' THEN 2
                    WHEN occupation = 'Actor' THEN 3
                    WHEN occupation = 'Professor' THEN 4 END)
```

Comment: UNION kills any ordering even when you set it in separate queries. Use external sorting.

Comment: The order by inside the sub query is useless without `limit` clause.

Comment: Select only one DBMS and remove excess tag. Use `GROUP BY` with `ROLLUP` instead of 2 queries and UNION.

Comment: Changing the UNION to UNION ALL will probably make it do what you want.  It is not formally guaranteed to, though.